# What does "permutation invariant" mean in the context of transformers doing language modelling?

Tags: pytorch, huggingface-transformers

I am reading a research paper called **LiLT**, their they mentioned `transformers are permutation invariant`. what is the meaning of permutation invariant in case of language modelling? [**link to paper**](https://paperswithcode.com/paper/lilt-a-simple-yet-effective-language)

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since all tokens in the sequence are treated equally in transformers, changing the order of the input tokens (=permutation) would result in the same output (=invariance). To avoid this, one adds positional embeddings, which are just numbers in each token, that represent its position in the sequence.

Eg. in language modelling *"I traveled from France to England and saw "* should result in something like *"London"* as the next word. But without the positional embeddings, the transformer cant differentiate between the correct sentence and *"I traveled from England to France and saw "*. So it might as well respond with *"Paris"*. The order of words matters. Thereby, permutation invariance is bad in language modelling.